# Disable checkbox for certain rows in reactdatagrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid

I am using reactdatagrid([reactdatagrid.io](https://reactdatagrid.io) not adazzle's [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid)). I have a checkbox column and I would want to disable the checkbox only for certain rows. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

You can pass an object to ReactDataGrid's checkboxColumn prop. Example of such object:

```js
const checkboxColumn = {
  renderCheckbox: (checkboxProps, cellProps) => {
    const { onChange, checked } = checkboxProps

    return (
      <Checkbox
        disabled={true}
        onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          onChange(!checked);
        }}
      >
      </Checkbox>
    );
  }
}
```